# Selenium in FireFox

Tags: java, selenium, firefox

I try to do my test with Selenium in Firefox but get this Error. I use Java as Language: (Exception in thread "main"

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: The driver server has
> unexpectedly died! Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision:
> 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:48')

```
System (Mac)
Jdk version : 16
Selenium Jar : 3.14.0
Geckodriver : 29
Firefox version : 88.0.1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Firefox version : 88.0.1
```

is compatible with  `Geckodriver 0.29.1`

download geckodriver latest from official website [here](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases)

Comment: I did It and i got this Error :

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: The driver server has unexpectedly died!